# Jamulus install from tar won't compile

Tags: compiling, tar

I am trying to install Jamulus. I can get the tar via the terminal. It says it saved it but when i compile using *cd jamulus-latest* as per the read me file, I get a *no such file or directory* message.

Comment: You have to unpack "the tar" first. Read `man tar`.

Comment: See https://jamulus.io/wiki/Installation-for-Linux .

Comment: Everything seemed to work as per the jamulus wiki until I tried to compile. That's when I got the no such file message.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I had copied & pasted the command to get the download and neglected the command to unzip it<tar -xvf latest.tar.gz>
I am a novice at using the command line and had neglected that step.
Thanks for the responses.